# Oracle 11g PL/SQL parallel execution to write into xml files

Tags: xml, oracle, file-io, oracle11g, parallel-processing

I have 5 million rows in a table, my requirement is to write all the rows into xml files.
As of now I am writing 10000 rows into one xml file and so on.(serially) it is taking so much time to write. is there any way to do this in parallel.

if possible, i want to write 10000 rows simultaneously into 5 files at a given time,
Each time it has to process 5 files in 5 parallel process(10000 rows each), if any of the process completes its task it has to pick the next 10000 rows into another process.

Comment: Since 11.2 you can use dbms_parallel_execute to chunkify your workload: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_parallel_ex.htm#ARPLS233

Comment: i want to do this from oracle database Schema only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create table(FOR_XML) with VArchar2(2000) column and use loop-for to write this 5 million rows grouped and ordered into Varchar2(2000) rows as small number of rows as you can. Then Select from this table and write in one xml file.

Second solution: create xml file, open with Wordpad, then `select * from FOR_XML` and click copy to excel(xlsx) then copy from excel this rows without head into wordpad. save and reopen xml and delete first space. It is fastest way. but not programmatic.